# set relative path for jar file in .classpath file eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium-webdriver

I have created a **customer jar in the parent folder** of my java testng maven project.
After adding it as external jar, the absolute path is getting created in **".classpath"** file.

Since multiple people are working on the same project, the **absolute path** would give an error. To resolve this issue, I want to create a **relative path** in ".classpath" file for the external jar file.

Have tried multiple options but none is working

Example:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="./../common.jar"/>
```

or

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="../common.jar"/>
```

or

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="**/common.jar"/>
```

As multiple projects are going to use this custom jar have placed it in the parent folder.

Can anyone suggest how to create a relative path for the same?

Comment: the first method is the correct one and it should work (works for me). Remember that the "." folder is the one mentioned in the : right click the project in the project explorer and choose properties.

Answer (score 0):

Do it the *Maven way*. Put the `common.jar` in your Nexus/Artifactory (which you set up on a company server if you do not already have one) and reference it as dependency in your Maven `pom.xml`.

Putting jars into project directories is not done in Maven.

Answer (score -1):

You first have to link the JAR file into the workspace to be able to add it to the *Java Build Path*:

1. ***File > New > File***
2. In the *New File* dialog click on ***Advanced >>***
3. Check the checkbox ***Link to file in file system***
4. Enter **`PARENT-1-PROJECT_LOC/common.jar`** as location
5. Click ***Finish*** to close the dialog
6. **Right-click** on the JAR file and choose ***Build Path > Add to Build Path***

The relative link will be stored in the `.project` file, whereas the `.classpath` file references the JAR file as if it were in the project (`path="common.jar"`).

Instead of linked files or folders, I would recommend a common project that contains all common JARs:

- In the common project export all JARs: In ***Project > Properties***, tab ***Order and Export*** select all JARs by checking the checkboxes
- In projects that make use of the common JARs: In ***Project > Properties***, tab ***Projects*** add the common project

Comment: Thanx. This worked but I am not sure whether it is an optimal solution or not

Comment: I would recommend a common project (see my extended answer).